# MPI broadcast changes the address of Python class instances

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am developing a python framework for a scientific application that I recently wanted to speed up a little using mpi4py. That framework works with, say, 3-4 class instances that do stuff with each other and each one store a reference to the other instance in a self.variable.

What troubles me is that the broadcasting function bcast changes the address of the instances each time. To make this work, I have to reassign the variable name (the new reference), of each instance, back to all the other instances. That makes me think that I am doing things wrong.

I reproduce this with the following piece of code where, each time the bcast function is called, the instance 'obj' changes address.

```
from mpi4py import MPI

commMPI = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rankMPI = commMPI.Get_rank()
sizeMPI = commMPI.Get_size()

class Dummy():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

if rankMPI == 0:
    obj = Dummy()
else:
    obj = None

obj  = commMPI.bcast(obj,root=0)
obj1 = obj

obj  = commMPI.bcast(obj,root=0)

print(rankMPI,obj is obj1)
```

I have just started using mpi4py so I only know the very basics. Do I have to implement an intrinsic class method to update the instances while keeping their primary address? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I found that I can retain the address of the root (rank 0) if I write this like

```
tmp = commMPI.bcast(obj,root=0)
if rankMPI != 0:
    obj = tmp
```

Is that how I should do it or there is a clearer way to write that?

Comment: I don't really understand why you think they should be the same reference. AFAICT `bcast` returns an entirely new object.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's what I wanted to learn. I could not find anywhere this "bcast returns an entirely new object". I understand the logic that for every process, except the root, a new object is created, but why the root itself is also replaced? In any case, for what I would like to do, is the approach that I described in the *Update* correct?